# category-block below product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I need display category-block below product page in template file .phtml
But this code not work.
Can you help me?

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                    ->setBlockId($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage())
                    ->toHtml();


        if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                ->setBlockId($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage())
                ->toHtml();
             $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
        }
         return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this  on phtml file

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()>0){
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                ->setBlockId(Mage::registry('current_category')->getLandingPage())
                ->toHtml();
}

}
```

but is depends on `Mage::registry('current_category')`.  Magento is set this registry variable `when getLastVisitedCategoryId() in catalog session` or magento product  have

```
category id in original routering url
```

Check this at `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product function of  function initProduct`

Comment: It's work good but like quote you depends on Mage::registry('current_category').

Comment: It's work good but like quote you depends on Mage::registry('current_category'). I need display block indipendently to current_category but for membership to category.